# Rust no_std ESP32 hal | ADC & DMA at 192 kHz sample rate

Tags: rust, esp32, dma, adc, rust-embedded

I’m trying to implement ADC conversion in a non blocking mode using DMA from gpio analog input at the sample rates: 192kHz.

###### My questions:

How to be implemented ADC in non-blocking mode (DMA). Something like:

```
    // DMA
    let dma = pdma::Dma::new(system.dma,  &mut system.peripheral_clock_control);
    dma.alloc_buffer::<u64>(256);
    let dmaChannel = dma....
    ...
```

###### Already tried:

- ADC in blocking mode (polling)

```
#![no_std]
#![no_main]
#![allow(non_snake_case)]

use esp_backtrace as _;
use esp_println::println;
use esp32_hal::{
    prelude::*,
    peripherals::Peripherals,
    clock::{ClockControl, CpuClock}, 
    Rtc, 
    timer::TimerGroup, 
    adc::{self, ADC1, AdcConfig, ADC, Attenuation}, 
    IO, 
    Delay,
};

#[entry]
fn main() -> ! {
    let peripherals = Peripherals::take();
    let mut system = peripherals.DPORT.split();
    let clocks = ClockControl::configure(system.clock_control, CpuClock::Clock240MHz).freeze();
    let io = IO::new(peripherals.GPIO, peripherals.IO_MUX);

    // Disable the RTC and TIMG watchdog timers
    let rtcCntl = Rtc::new(peripherals.RTC_CNTL);
    let mut rwdt = rtcCntl.rwdt;
    let timer_group0 = TimerGroup::new(peripherals.TIMG0, &clocks);
    let mut wdt0 = timer_group0.wdt;
    let timer_group1 = TimerGroup::new(peripherals.TIMG1, &clocks);
    let mut wdt1 = timer_group1.wdt;
    rwdt.disable();
    wdt0.disable();
    wdt1.disable();

    // ADC
    let analog = peripherals.SENS.split();
    let mut adcConfig: AdcConfig<ADC1> = adc::AdcConfig::new();
    let mut adcPin = adcConfig.enable_pin(
        io.pins.gpio34.into_analog(), 
        Attenuation::Attenuation11dB,
    );
    let mut adc1 = ADC::<ADC1>::adc(analog.adc1, adcConfig).unwrap();

    let mut delay = Delay::new(&clocks);
    loop {
        match nb::block!(adc1.read(&mut adcPin)) {
            Ok(value) => {
                println!("{}", value);
                value
            },
            Err(err) => {
                println!("ADC1 read error: {:?}", err);
                0
            },
        };
        delay.delay_ms(1_u32);
    };
}
```

- ADC in non-blocking mode (interrupt)

it’s worked only at lower frequencies (up to 1 kHz).

Need to be implemented ADC in non-blocking mode (DMA)t o free up the cpu for another tasks, like transferring samples from adc via Ethernet and some DSP tasks.